# How to use curl with proxy setting that username contains @domain

Tags: curl, proxy

My company uses a web proxy to get to the internet. I know how to use -x user:pass@proxy:port. However, my challenge is that my login for the proxy uses username@domain.com and a password to login to the proxy. How would you format the proxy string?

I tried to escape the @ with \@ in the user portion, but it tries to resolve the domain, which it shouldn't. I also tried with single & double quotes, but I get the same result.

$ curl -I http://www.google.com -x first.last\@example.com:mypass@web-proxy.example.com http://www.google.com
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: example.com
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: example.com

TIA

Comment: did you try http escaping '@' -> '%40' ?

Comment: Wow! That was easy.